# Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt) on (../secrets.json)

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have a playbook where I want to copy a vault-encrypted json file (and unencrypt on the way) to a raspberry.
I encrypted the file using

```
ansible-vault encrypt secrets.json
```

Viewing and decrypting works, also running the playbook with `--ask-vault-pass`. I tried this a couple of times yesterday and it does what it should, but after *a while* the error mentioned in the title seems to pop up, *no matter* if I run the playbook or try to explicitly decrypt/view the file. It seems to "forget" it is a correctly encrypted file. This happened with a few encryption attempts, always after a certain amount of time (~1h). I did not change anything in the meantime as `git` confirms.

The copy command in the playbook:

```
    - name: copy secrets.json
      copy:
        src: ../secrets.json
        dest: raspberry/secrets.json
        decrypt: yes
        owner: pi
        mode: '0700'
        group: pi
```

I installed `ansible` via `pipx`:

```
pipx install --include-deps ansible

ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.2]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/michael/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/michael/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/michael/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/michael/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.2 (main, Feb 16 2022, 01:19:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

My password contains only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: That's odd, but since the encryption algorithm is AES256 with a salt, maybe a time misconfiguration could cause that? Try to check the time of your nodes and their corresponding NTP configuration, maybe?

Comment: You'll want to pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section since as written no one can possibly **guess** what you're running. MCVE still applies even with cryptographic questions as the example can include fake secrets and hard-coded passwords. The posted question doesn't have to _consistently_ fail, cause I hear you about the nondeterministic behavior, but meet us half way with _something_. Good luck